# Akka Router Implementation

Tags: java, java-8, akka, actor

I am practicing Akka routing and found this code in the Akka docs.

Router class:

```
public class Router extends AbstractActor {

    private List<Routee> routees = new ArrayList<Routee>();

    akka.routing.Router router;
    {

        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
            ActorRef actor = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(Actor.class));
            getContext().watch(actor);
            routees.add(new ActorRefRoutee(actor));
            System.out.println("Routee added");
        }

        router = new akka.routing.Router(new RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), routees);

    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(Work.class, work -> {
                    router.route(work, getSender());
                })
                .match(Terminated.class, terminated -> {

                    System.out.println("Got actor terminated message");

                    router.removeRoutee(new ActorRefRoutee(terminated.actor()));
                    ActorRef actor = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(Actor.class));
                    getContext().watch(actor);
                    router.addRoutee(new ActorRefRoutee(actor));

                    System.out.println("Routee added back");
                })
                .build();
    }
}
```

Actor class:

```
public class Actor extends AbstractActor {

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(Work.class, work -> {
                    System.out.println("Work message received");
                    getContext().stop(getSelf());
                })
                .build();
    }
}
```

The `Router` class creates five instances of the `Actor` class. The instances are stored in a list. And I am applying a `RoundRobinRoutingLogic` to it when configuring the router.

When I send five or fewer messages, it works perfectly. But when the number of messages exceeds five, it is showing a dead letters error. Why? I am adding a new routee each time a routee is stopped. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actor starting and stopping, as well as the generation of the `Terminated` message, happen asynchronously. What this means in the context of your question is that you cannot guarantee, with your current setup, that a fresh routee has been added to the router before the router receives the sixth message. Probably what is happening is that the router is churning through the messages so quickly that when the sixth `Work` message arrives, there are no routees available yet.

As an aside, it's very confusing to name your classes "Router" and "Actor," since the Akka API already uses those words.

Comment: The routees which are created are being watched by the Router class. So each time a routee dies, terminated message will be sent back. At that moment I remove the routee and I replace it with a new one. This shouldnt show dead letters message right? @chunjef

Comment: @bumblebee: Updated.